# Java arrange 3d map

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

so i have this data structure:

Segment - Column Number - Value

- "title" - 1 - Foo
- "title" - 2 - Foo
- "title" - 3 - Foo
- "content" - 1 - Foo
- "content" - 2 - Foo
- "content" - 3 - Foo

and so on... `<String, Intenger, String> or <Integer, Integer, String>`

I'm actually parsing data and adding it to a HashMap:

```
map.put(1, parser.query(job.getString("title")));
map.put(2, parser.query(job.getString("date")));
map.put(3, parser.query(job.getString("content")));
map.put(4, parser.query(job.getString("href")));
```

the 2nd parameter is a 2D array. It's the column number and value.

What i want to do is something like that

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++)
{
    db.put(
        map.get("title").get(1),
        map.get("content").get(1),
        ...
    );
}
```

The second column in the HashMap is a list but as the get() method returns objects, i'm not able to write something like that. What is the best way to handle such data ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `get()` method doesn't return Object in Java 5+. It returns an instance of the generic type of the list. Use a generic List. If you don't understand what I mean, show us how you declared the map.

Comment: oh gosh... i forgot the generic type in the arguments. Thank you and sorry for my dumbness!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `.get()`, then the value for your first `Map` can't be a two-dimensional array.

There's no three-dimensional map, but there is a `Map` of `Map`s.  The syntax for that would be `Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>`.  Mind you that this still preserves the key-value ordering that `Map`s have - the key is `String`, and the *value* is another `Map` of `<Integer, String>`.

Here's some example syntax:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> multiMap = new HashMap<>();

HashMap<Integer, String> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put(Integer.valueOf(1), "Foo");
multiMap.put("title", innerMap);
System.out.println(multiMap.get("title").get(Integer.valueOf(1))); // prints Foo
```